# How to Solve this Format of Integration

Tags: integration

In general if I want to solve an integral of type-

$$\int \frac{1}{x^n+a^m} \ dx$$

Where $a$ is a constant and $n$ and $m$ are any rational numbers.

How can I start to solve this integral. I know there can be certain substitutions which depend from question to question but I want a mechanical process to use in case of emergencies i.e. when no substitution or other method strikes my mind.

Maybe you can consider it to be equivalent to me trying to write a program to integrate any function of this type in a computer.

I know the standard results for instance when $n=2$ this can be expressed as $\arctan$.

I'm more concerned with cases for instance where m and n are not equal.

For example when $n=1.5$ and $m=-9.2$

Or something of this sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^n+a^m}$$

Substitute $$x^n=a^m y \\ x=a^{m/n} y^{1/n} \\ dx = \frac{1}{n} a^{m/n} y^{1/n-1} dy$$

Now we have:

$$I=a^{m/n-m} \int \frac{y^{1/n-1}dy}{1+y}$$

This is a more "canonical" form for this integral. The result in general can be expressed as a hypergeometric function or incomplete beta function.

Comment: What does a more canonical form mean? More generally seen form?

Comment: @StackUpPhysics, no, I mean the form usually associated with hypergeometric or incomplete beta functions. You can look up the integral definitions (wikipedia for example) and see that this one looks very similar. $$ \mathrm {B} (x;\,a,b)=\int _{0}^{x}t^{a-1}\,(1-t)^{b-1}\,dt$$ $$\mathrm {B} (b,c-b)\,_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;z)=\int _{0}^{1}x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a}\,dx$$

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the info and the answer

Comment: @StackUpPhysics, you are welcome!

Comment: I just wanted to ask this I've seen people use mathjax or supposedly some code like you have in the comment however it doesn't load on my phone rather all I see is a code is this a bug?

Comment: @StackUpPhysics, it's MathJax, you can add it to a comment the same way you add it to a post. As for display issues, sometimes MathJax doesn't process on my phone either. Reloading usually fixes the problem. The code for the integrals for this comment I lifted directly from Wikipedia